# TypeError: d is not a function in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Im using jsplumb

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src= "http://theanalyticstreedemo.cloudapp.net:81/NanoClientApplication/js/JsPlumb/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src= "http://localhost:8082/NanoClientApplication/newWebApp/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

jsPlumb.makeSource($(e), {
   anchor:"Continuous",
   endpoint:["Rectangle", { width:40, height:20 }],
   maxConnections:3
});
```

While making a connection dynamically im getting `TypeError: d is not a function` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond out the solution for this,
`jquery-ui.min.js` loading multiple times